# What can I do when the upholstery on my computer chair is coming off?

Tags: furniture

My computer chair, a fantastic chair that has served me well, is starting to lose its upholstery at the bottom of the seat and back.  I'd like to preserve the chair for as long as possible. How can I protect it from damage, especially down towards the back and bottom where it's already started wearing out?

I've already started using a seat cushion to protect the seat part of my chair, but it doesn't cover the lower back that I lean back on, and because my chair is connected from the top of the back to the seat, I can't just slip a seat cover on it because it wouldn't fit.

Answer (score 1):

You could buy or make your own [slipcover for computer chair](//google.com/search?q=slipcover+for+computer+chair), and focus on getting a kind which either is in two parts with one part for the back, and one for the seat, or a "one-piece" which slips on the back and extends forward over the seat.

The last one can also be hacked using a long blanket. Put the blanket over the seat, up the back and over the top of back. Fasten it together so that the topmost part of the blanket forms a pocket over the back of the chair. To fasten you can either stitch it together, use some safety pins, or if your in a real pinch staple it together.

It can also be an advantage to tie a thin rope (or similar) around the back in the area between the seat and the back of chair to keep the extra fabric close to the back, and prevent it from slipping forward.

If the chair is clearly divided in a back rest and seat part, you can instead of one piece of fabric use two parts possibly with a sewn elastic to kind of make "fitted sheets" for each part.

Comment: For a chair with a cushion seat, it's easy to recover it with heavy-duty fabric. Since I've done it without trouble, it's trivial. Tools needed: screw-driver, scissors and stapler. If its a sling-type seat, you might make a replacement piece, or use an iron-on patch.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new seat cover out of duct tape.  If you can [make a wallet with it](https://www.google.com/search?q=duct%20tape%20wallet&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=909&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjaocmzz8bOAhVS02MKHfyCCmgQsAQIGw), even [build a boat out of it](https://www.google.com/search?q=duct%20tape%20boat&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=909&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNibLCz8bOAhUS8mMKHT10CZcQsAQIGw), you can fix your computer chair.