# Durable office chair covering

Tags: furniture

I am looking to make a cushion for this chair that will cover the wear spots on the chair.

The chair is pretty comfortable.

The bottom of the seat is 20 inches by 18 and the back is 20 by 22 inches.

I am open to any ideas.

[image]

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: @Shadow The Kid Wizard I am looking for a cover that will outlast my current covering. The existing cover is flaking apart and cracking at the seams.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do when the upholstry on my computer chair is coming off?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7426/what-can-i-do-when-the-upholstry-on-my-computer-chair-is-coming-off)

Answer (score 1):

The obvious to me answer is leather. But it may cost more to re-cover the chair than that the chair is worth, especially if you have to have it done. Heavy canvas will also work.

The cheap option is to get second hand leather from leather covered furniture that is broken and is going to be ditched and to do the recovering yourself, but it is not going to be easy.

The easy option is to forget this chair and get one like it, possibly the same one second hand.

If you decide not to re-cover but still want to keep this chair you can sew a seat cover.
The basic seat cover is a rectangle which is folded round the seat cushion and fixed in place there.
But it will not be naturally a good fit and might not be very comfy.

Comment: I bought some denim fabric, elastic, and thick foam cushion. My tailor will sew it into a cushion. Cover will be removable for cleaning.

Answer (score 1):

You should repair the "pleather" by peeling off what is loose and then painting on a repair product such as an acrylic black fabric paint that they sell at craft stores. They also sell a satin acrylic finisher that you can recoat the repair and other wear points on the chair for durability. This is an easy, fairly inexpensive and do-able fix. You can do it!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

I bought the fabric and foam from a fabric store.

A local tailor assembled this.

It has elastic so it can be easily washed.